# loss of attribute data when copying between layers

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-2.2

[image]
I am trying to copy points from one layer to another in QGIS 2.2

The problem I get is that all the attribute data from the copied points is missing when copied onto the new layer, the columns show up as blank.

Both layers have the same columns.

Is this a problem with 2.2 or is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of the fields tab from the properties of both layers.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the attributes tables, I have not had this problem with previous versions of QGIS

Comment: Turns out it was just a case of quitting QGIS and reopening it again, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: For me it's working within a QGIS instance but not over two instances (2.18.16).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Processing* plugin which, once downloaded and installed, has the functions **Merge Vector Layers** or **Join Attributes Table**.

Comment: Only problem is that i do not want to copy all the points over, only a few

Comment: Ah yes, that little bug. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely because you are attempting to copy directly from a .MDB file.  I have just noticed this issue copying sewer and manhole features within a .MDB to another shapefile.  IT doesn't happen every time, but probably has something to do with linking of attribute fields.

Fix:  Export those layers (you are trying to copy from) to another shapefile saved outside of the original .MDB database file.  You should be able to copy and paste freely between this new shapefile(s) and one of identical geometry and attribute fields.